# Order of group $A\Gamma L_d(F)$ of Affine semi-linear transformation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields, affine-geometry

**Question** What is the order of a group $A\Gamma L_d(q)$ of Affine semilinear transformation ? (here $q$ is a prime power of some prime $p$).

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $q=p^f$. The group is a semidirect product of three groups:

- a $d$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_q$-vector space of size $q^d$
- $\mathrm{GL}(d,q)$ of size $(q^d-1)(q^d-q)\ldots(q^d-q^{d-1})$.
- a cyclic group of order $f$ generated by the Frobenius automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Now multiply the three factors.